# Best way to optimize joomla cache. Difference between Global configuration cache and system cache plugin

Tags: seo, joomla, cache, optimization, load-time

I need to know for a Joomla site

> there is system cache plugin
>
> then there is global configuration setting to enable cache - how is it different from system cache plugin

below are some of speed optimization i have already done

> Enabled system cache plugin
>
> ExpiresActive On with ExpiresByType done
>
> AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE done

My site has mostly database queries been updated in terms of new product listings.
Does enabling global configuration conservative cache can also help in reduce loading time (despite face where we have already enabled joomla system cache)

How is Global configuration conservative cache different from joomla system cache plugin. What is the difference
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the global settings version caches the views and parameters of components and modules, rather than the content.  This means that if you change the content, then the change will be instantly visible to users.

However, this method of caching may not be a feature of third-party components (Joomla states [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Cache): `Component developers have to include this in their code to work.`)

The plugin saves whole pages in a temporary directory, so if you change the content, then you are likely to still see the old version until the cache is cleared.

There is a nice overview of how the plugin works [here](http://www.faresweb.net/tutorials/joomla-extension-system-cache-plugin).